# codeigniter query binding and escate_str not sufficient

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm developing an web app with codeigniter and I am struggling with escape issues..

I send my parameter(json with lots of text) like

```
$this->Upload_model->upload(array($this->db->escape_str($myjson),$this->db->escape_str($myjson1),$this->db->escape_str($myjson2)));
```

and in upload, I use querybindings like

```
$query = $this->db->query("insert into qwerty (_title, _desid, _short,_options, _status, _current) values (?,".$did.",?,?,1,0)", $datain);
```

but these techniques do not seem to properly escape single quotes

querybindings actually do nothing to the sql queries and escape_str adds // infront of 's but they do not seem to work.

it seems that this is because of json+mysql but I cannot come up with my own solution

can anyone help me out

//error log : theres a single quote in front of that t in the lorem ipsum
    Error Number: 1064

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsu' at line 1
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with CodeIgniter, but if you bind your values to placeholders, you should not need to escape anything.

Comment: thought so too but I suddenly got an error

Comment: what is in the $datain ?

Comment: @KaliDass $datain is the array given as parameter

Comment: are you checked the JSON input after escape_str ? use this : jsonlint.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The benefit of using binds is that the values are automatically escaped, producing safer queries. You don’t have to remember to manually escape data; the engine does it automatically for you.

So don't need to escaping queries input.

Refer https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html#query-bindings

Comment: you mean I got that error because I used escape_str?

Comment: are you checked the JSON input after escape_str ? use this : http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: what do you mean by checking json? I've made it with json_encode and there's no way that its not going to be an appropriate json

Comment: escape_str will escape the strings in the json file like ' / so the problem occurred

Comment: but the same errors are occuring without escape_str

Comment: can give the raw SQL querie

Comment: can you post the raw sql query with data ?

Comment: I was doing something very stupid... I wasn't actually handling the right method in the model